# How to configure apache vhosts in parallel with Ansible

Tags: ansible

### Problem

I'm configuring apache vhosts with ansible. It takes a lot of time to create the configs.

Version info:

- ansible-playbook 2.7.10
- Apache/2.4.29

All vhosts are on the same server.
I'm using the file system structure that Apache suggests:

One file per site (vhost and used port) which will be saved to sites-available/443_example.com.conf. Then I generate a symlink to sites-enabled.

Sequentially running the tasks for the configuration takes about 5 minutes for 34 vhosts if there are no changes.

I created a role for the apache configuration. I identified 13 tasks that have to be run for every vhost:

1. openssl_privatekey
2. openssl_csr
3. openssl_certificate
4. 6 tasks: place the files on the correct places in the file system but only if there is no Let's Encrypt configuration present
5. create template
6. enable template
7. 2 tasks: delete old config

For example writing the config template, generate a self signed certificate.

It would be nice if I can parallelize these vhosts. I grouped the tasks I want to run in parallel in the file parallel.yml. The content of this file has to be processed in the correct order.

### Solutions

These are the solutions I tried but none of them worked:

#### 1) use async on every task:

I'm using a template in parallel.yml and this cannot be asynced.

#### 2) use one async while including tasks:

```
- name: 'configure vhost'
  include_tasks: parallel.yml
  loop: "{{ vhosts }}"
  async: 60
```

There is a know issue that makes Ansible ignore the the async. The loop items are processed serial https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/22716

#### 3) use "delegate to" to create more forks of Ansible:

```
- name: 'configure vhost'
  include_tasks: parallel.yml
  loop: "{{ vhosts }}"
  delegate_to: ansible@example.com
```

The loop items are processed serial https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/37995

#### 4) use strategy: free

"A second strategy ships with Ansible - free - which allows each host to run until the end of the play as fast as it can." https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_strategies.html

strategy: free allows multiple hosts to be run in parallel. That doesn't work on one host only.

#### 5) increase forks

"Since Ansible 1.3, the fork number is automatically limited to the number of possible hosts at runtime," https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.4/intro_configuration.html#forks

Same problem as before.

### Summary

How can I run the tasks in parallel?

How can I improve the performance?

Comment: Can your provide more information about what is happening inside parallel.yml? Have you looked into using the [strategy: free](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_strategies.html) directive for your play?

Comment: Hi Flotastisch, welcome to SO. Are you aware of the [`--forks`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.7/cli/ansible-playbook.html#cmdoption-ansible-playbook-f) option of `ansible-playbook`? You may also enjoy reading about [mitogen](https://mitogen.networkgenomics.com/ansible_detailed.html) which is dramatically faster in most cases

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I added a paragraph to strategy: free, to forks and about parallel.yml
I have to check out mitogen later.

Comment: mitogen is really nice. The perfomance increased from 4:51 min to 1:27 for 414 tasks.